# Test automation: how to test changing elements with Robot Framework?

Tags: selenium, automation, robotframework

I'm using Robot Framework + Selenium (Java version) and I need to test a background that keeps changing images every few seconds using some sort of javascript.

It's basically four < div > elements that contain images that get added the class "active" every one or two seconds. So if the first background is being displayed then the HTML shows something like this:

```
<div class="background first active">
<div class="background second">
<div class="background third">
<div class="background fourth">
```

and after a second it goes to something like this:

```
<div class="background first">
<div class="background second active">
<div class="background third">
<div class="background fourth">
```

So what I need to do is check that indeed this "active" class is being applied to < div > after < div > in a loop. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: There's nothing special you need to do. Find the active background. Wait a few seconds find the active background. Compare to see if they are the same or different.

Comment: Can you update the question with you code trials and the exact `interval` of image change? A formatted text based `HTML` of the `DOM` will help us for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the Robot framework to do this. You can do it with just Selenium. Here's one way you can do this...

```
By first = By.cssSelector("div.background.first.active");
By second = By.cssSelector("div.background.second.active");
By third = By.cssSelector("div.background.third.active");
By fourth = By.cssSelector("div.background.fourth.active");
waitForCycle(first);
waitForCycle(second);
waitForCycle(third);
waitForCycle(fourth);
```

and a support function

```
public static void waitForCycle(By locator)
{
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(locator));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(locator));
}
```

You define the active state in the locators at the start. You then call the helper function, one at a time. The helper function waits for the located element to be visible and then invisible.

This should detect first becoming active and then not active. Then second becoming active and then not active... and so on.

If you ever get a `TimeoutException`, you know that one of the cycles failed. You could add a `try-catch` around each one if you want a "pretty" message of which one failed but it should be apparent by the locator in the exception which one was being waited on.

Comment: The same logic can be implemented using Robot Script by using `Wait Until Element Is Visible  css=div.background.first.active  5s   Image did not show within the given total loop time.` for each image.

Comment: @A.Kootstra You should post that as a separate answer. Someone in the future may find it helpful.

Comment: Thanks :) I actually can't use Selenium as I can't extend the RF library I'm using. But the option by @A.Kootstra sounds interesting :)